# How to create a calendar table for 30 days prior to today in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am a newbie in SAS.

I am trying to create a simple table in SAS that has three columns, date (for thirty days prir to today), how_many_days_before (representing the number of days between date and today ), and which_day (showing the name of that date as monday, tuesday, etc).

Edit: Here is the code I tried. I want to automate the macros with loops. Also the output table has blank values for which_day and how_many_days_before variables for now.

```
%macro which_day;
   if date=160822 then which_day='monday';
   else if date=160821 then which_day='sunday';
%mend;
%macro how_many_days_before;
 if date=160822 then how_many_days_before=0;
 else if date=160821 then how_many_days_before=1;
%mend;
data calendar;
  attrib date format=yymmdd6.;
  do date=today()-30 to today();
    output;
  end;
  %which_day;
  %how_many_days_before;
run;
```

I have tried intnx function without a luck.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so that we can see where you are having trouble.  The people on StackOverflow are happy to help fix problems but are not a code writing service.

Comment: Your image doesn't inform what you're trying to do based on your question.

Comment: Hello Robert, and Reeza, you are right, I am sorry. Forgive me as this was my first post.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code, but it should give you a starter. Hope it helps

```
data calendar;
  attrib date today format=date9.;
  do date=today()-30 to today();
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write it in data step without using macros.

```
data calendar;
  attrib date format=yymmdd6.;
  do date=today()-30 to today();
    how_many_days=today()-date;
    which_day=weekday(date);
    output;
  end;
run;
```